# How can insert a symbol "&" in a string in PyQT

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

How can i insert a a symbol\operator "&"  between the strings in python Qt QPushbutton

```
Apply_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Apply & Change")
```

i get the buttontext as

```
Apply Change
```

but the 'and &'  symbol is missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

& Works like shortcut on Qt, try using &&

Answer (score 1):

If the text contains an ampersand (`&`), a shortcut will be created using the next character. To insert an actual ampersand, use `&&`.